# How do I reference a class defined inside my superclass?

Tags: c++, oop, superclass

I have a superclass with a class defined inside it. like:

```
class A {
 public:
  class B {public: bool value;};

  A() {
      DoStuff(b_);
  }
  B b_;
 private:
  virtual void DoStuffImpl(B& b) = 0;
  void DoStuff(B& b) { return DoStuffImpl(b); }
};

class X : public A {
  // ...
 private:
  virtual void DoStuffImpl(B& b);
  void UseBForSomethingElse(B& b);
};

void X::DoStuffImpl(B& b) {
    UseBForSomethingElse(b);
}

void X::UseBForSomethingElse(B& b) {
    b.value = true;
}

int main(){
    X x;
    return x.b_.value;
}
```

My compiler seems to understand that `DoStuffImpl()` just fine. But, when I added `UseBForSomethingElse()`, the compiler could not find the definition for the `B` class. I tried to further specify by doing `bool UseBForSomethingElse(A::B& b)`. This compiled, but then failed during linking.

How do I correctly specify the parent `B`, and why does it work for the virtual function but not the other one?

Comment: Can you give a minimum example so that we can copy-paste, compile and see the error? Also, what is your compiler (name and version)?

Comment: http://ideone.com/OMOtxK

Comment: I may have been sleeping the day you could override a *private* pure virtual function. It wouldn't be the first time I was sleeping at the proverbial language-wheel.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You see, this is why i spend my time following your posts, Luchian =P. I learn new shiat all the time, and I've been doing this *way* too long to be saying that. (but at least i admit it)

Comment: @WhozCraig I agree. Why isn't it `protected`? Can't explain that, but it was written by someone else, and it works, so.... ? @Luchian can you explain how the subclass can "see" the private virtual function?

Comment: Btw, Robert, compiles without problem on LLVM 4.1 on my Mac. What toolset are you using (update the question please, so it is glaring for all to see without having to scan comments).

Comment: Compiles without problem with ``gcc 4.8``

Comment: Compiles with no problem with GCC 4.2

Comment: `private` doesn't make things invisible. That's Java, not C++. When a base class has a function that's marked `virtual` and a derived class has a function with the same signature, the function in the derived class overrides the function in the base class. Full stop.

Comment: @RobertMartin the method is still seen. It can't be called, but it's still seen. :)

Comment: As to why it isn't protected, apparently it doesn't need to be protected. The reason for making a base class member function protected is to allow derived class member functions to call it.

Comment: Regarding private-decls that override virtually, I've looked in section 10 and 11 of the spec, and can't seem to find the specifics of where virtual override ignores access-specifiers. I know its in there somewhere (must be) but I'm not as familiar with the spec as others (poke @LuchianGrigore) that may know. Sorry, Robert.

Comment: @WhozCraig 11.5 It should be noted that it is access to members and base classes that is controlled, not their visibility. Names
of members are still visible, and implicit conversions to base classes are still considered, when those members
and base classes are inaccessible.

Comment: @WhozCraig I updated the problem to be more specific. It fails to compile on ideone.com: http://ideone.com/hxKxfH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated post doesn't properly qualify UseBForSomethingElse().

```
void UseBForSomethingElse(const B& b)
```

should be

```
void X::UseBForSomethingElse(const B& b)
```

Once this is fixed, you still have a problem (and heaven help me if I get this wrong).

You're firing a virtual method from a base class constructor without the derived class finishing construction. I.e, UseBForSomethingElse (non-virtual) is fired from DoStuffImpl() (virtual, pure @ A, defined in X) **before** X is finished base-construction (you're, in fact *in* X's base-construction when you make the call). This will trigger a 'pure virtual function called' since X's vtable isn't fixed up until its constructor is actually entered.

This **does** happen on my machine as well, btw.

Comment: Okay. So fixing this turns it into a runtime exception on @Luchian's compiler: http://ideone.com/Qr1cqF

Comment: @RobertMartin mine as well, please see the updated answer above.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I'm becoming more or less confused :P I've (I think) fixed the constructor issue, and still getting a runtime error?  http://ideone.com/HBAqQO (I updated the question to reflect this)

Comment: Actually, I'll create a new question. This seems like an appropriate answer to my original. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT based on OP edit:

The reason ideone says you have a runtime error is because you're *returning 1 from main*. Any non-zero return value from `main` would be considered a failed execution. If you just change the return to `return !x.b_.value;` ideone reports success as expected.

Original answer:

```
void UseBForSomethingElse(const B& b) {
    b.value = true;
}
```

You can't assign into a constant reference (`b`), so that's certainly one of your problems.

Also, you didn't qualify the definition of `UseBForSomethingElse` with `X::` so the compiler doesn't put it in the scope of `X`, preventing it from seeing the parent's nested class.

Comment: Very possibly. Here is a version that fails without any `const`s: http://ideone.com/3J0vJK